# Can I create a Windows 7 recovery disk on a dual boot system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, system-recovery

I want to uninstall Ubuntu from a computer running both Ubuntu and Windows 7. I understand that to do this, I need to delete the Ubuntu partitions on the computer and use a windows recovery disk. Because I don't have a recovery disk, I plan to use the built in program on Windows 7 that lets you create one. Can I create a recovery disk using this program with Ubuntu on the computer, too?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can create a recovery disk. Windows does not care about other operating systems or partitions other than the C (or system) drive when creating recovery disks, performing recovery, etc. It limits it's operations to the system partition, AND sometimes the *System Reserved* partitions it creates itself during setup. You can create a recovery disk, boot into it and issue the following command on the recovery prompt to wipe out GRUB:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

After that, you can safely remove Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: I plan to use the howtogeek tutorial to uninstall Ubuntu. It's similar to yours, but it says that I should uninstall the Ubuntu partitions first, then create a recovery disk and type bootrec /fixmbr on command prompt from the repair disk. Does using howtogeek's instructions also work?

Comment: It's the same thing. Thing is, that if you remove the Ubuntu partitions, then you'll boot into GRUB which stores its menu on the Ubuntu partition. Since the menu would be gone, GRUB won't be able to boot any OS. You could remove the partitions first, given you have already CREATED the recovery disk from Windows. If you are locked out of Windows since you deleted the Ubuntu partition without removing GRUB, then it can be a menace.